# Swift: How to increase loading speed of images from documents?

Tags: ios, swift

My app saved photo to the local documents folder and I used the UICollectionView to display all the image from that folder. But whenever I try to open the CollectionView it often took several seconds to open. I'm thinking that maybe the image files are too big, each photo is around 10MB. I also tried using thumbnails to display in collectionview but it still too slow. Any idea how to speed that up?

```
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! SPCell
    // Configure the cell
    cell.imageView.image = loadImage(fileName: self.fileURLs[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}
func loadImagesFromDocuments(){
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let documentsURL = NSHomeDirectory() + "/Documents/Secure/"
    do {
        fileURLs = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: URL(string: documentsURL)!, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
    } catch {
        print("Error while enumerating files : \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

}

func loadImage(fileName: URL) -> UIImage? {
   do {
        let imageData = try Data(contentsOf: fileName)
        return UIImage(data: imageData)
    } catch {
        print("Error loading image : \(error)")
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: You likely want to downsample the images for better performance. [Here](https://nshipster.com/image-resizing/) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/219/) discuss the performance issues of image resizing.

Answer (score 0):

Current problem is that you load the image every time the cell appears so Instead of

```
var fileURLs = [URL]()
```

Make it

```
var fileImages = [UIImage]()
```

Then inside `viewDidLoad`

```
fileImages = fileURLs.compactMap { self.loadImage(fileName: $0) }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are synchronously loading images while returning every cell at indexPath.

```
cell.imageView.image = loadImage(fileName: self.fileURLs[indexPath.row])
```

Instead, you can create a custom UICollectionViewCell implementation with a variable in global scope say `imageURL`.

after cell initialization, do this:

```
cell.imageURL = self.fileURLs[indexPath.row]
```

and, in ViewDidLoad() of your custom class, add this line:

```
self.imageView.image = loadImage(fileName: self.imageURL)
```

doing so, will lead to images being loaded in each custom implementation of cell unblocking the thread which is invoking the DataSource of your CollectionView.